# How to create predicate to fetch all entities with not repeated results for the same property?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I need to implement FAQ for many languages. So I have created entity `Question` with following properties:

- `language`
- `collection` - to mark the same question in different languages

**Storing**

All of them are kept in iCloud in public database.

**Fetching**

Within an app I fetch all questions for `en` language and current language installed on the app. All is saved in core data.

**Displaying**

I need to display (using FRC) ALL questions for current language and all for english (if question with the same `collection` is not created for current language).

**Example (question, language, collection):**

```
Q1, pl, 1
Q2, pl, 3
Q3, en, 1
Q4, de, 1
Q5, es, 2
Q6, en, 2
```

If my current language is **pl** then I would like to fetch the following questions:

```
Q1, pl, 1
Q2, pl, 3
Q6, en, 2
```

How can I achieve that? I need to create NSPredicate to simply exclude those questions that are not expected to fetch them.

Comment: I guess you need a sub-query for this but I am not sure how to do one against the same entity. Is it a lot of date because one straight-forward option is to read everything for the two languages and remove the duplicates in code?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

You are over thinking this problem.  If you are dealing with less than 500 entities - which I assume you are - then there is very little performance difference between filtering through a query or doing an in memory filter after the fetch.  Also it seems like you do not have to deal with the objects changing after the fetch - so using a fecthedResultsController does not have a huge benefit.  Just fetch them all, and then filter and sort them like you would any array.

It might be worth considering not using core-data at all if you are not sorting and displaying user's data, and just downloading static data from a server - but I trust that you have already investigated those alternatives.

### Solution 2

You can solve this with a fecthedResultsController by using sectionKeyPath.  Sort the request by collection and then group them by collection.  Now every section represents a single collection.  Make the number of rows in the collectionView equal to the FRC number of sections.  For each row look in the section and choose the question with the most preferred language. This only works if you are sorting by the 'collection' key.  If you want to sort them differently you can change the 'collection' value not just an random int or a uuid, but be ordered in a way that you want.